# OpenLayers 2 Touch events for Windows

Tags: events, touch, openlayers, tablet

I'm using OpenLayers 2 and touch events (panning, pinch zoom, etc) are working fine on iPads/iPhones but not on Microsoft Tablets/Phones.

I tried implementing a solution offered on [this DotNet Blog](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/03/enabling-basic-openlayers-pinch-zooming.html), to no avail.

Specifically, I'm trying to get OpenLayers 2 touch navigation working on a Microsoft Surface Tablet.

Any ideas?